# Spring Security: How to get the originally thrown exception of a failed XwsSecurityInterceptor.validateMessage call

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ws

My application is using Spring Security to validate incoming Endpoint calls. I am trying to give the client specific error codes when anything goes wrong within the XwsSecurityInterceptor but I haven't yet found a way to do this.

This is what I have tried: I am using an EndpointInterceptor that inherits from XwsSecurityInterceptor:

```
<bean name="myInterceptor" id="myInterceptor" class="x.y.MyPreAuthenticationSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="policyConfiguration" value="classpath:/security.xml" />
    <property name="callbackHandlers">
        <list>
            <bean id="myCallbackHandler" class="x.y.MyCallbackHandler" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The interceptor has a CallbackHandler 'myCallbackHandler' that handles PasswordValidationCallbacks. For testing purposes for each callback it attaches a validator that will instantly throw a certain exception (CustomException) with a certain error code:

```
@Override
protected void handleInternal(Callback callback) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    if (callback instanceof PasswordValidationCallback) {
        PasswordValidationCallback validationCallback = (PasswordValidationCallback) callback;
        if (validationCallback.getRequest() instanceof PasswordValidationCallback.PlainTextPasswordRequest) {
            validationCallback.setValidator(new MyValidator());
            return;
        }
    } else if (callback instanceof CleanupCallback) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        return;
    }
    throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callback);
}

private class MyValidator implements PasswordValidationCallback.PasswordValidator {
    public boolean validate(PasswordValidationCallback.Request request) throws PasswordValidationCallback.PasswordValidationException 
    {
        throw new PasswordValidationCallback.PasswordValidationException("test", new CustomException("some error code"));
    }
}
```

As specified in https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/security.html, section 7.2.5 the exception handling is done in the handleValidationException method.

In 'MyPreAuthenticationSecurityInterceptor' I am overriding the handleValidationException  method:

```
@Override
public boolean handleValidationException(WsSecurityValidationException ex, MessageContext messageContext) {
    if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
        logger.warn("Could not validate request: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Problem is that when debugging I can't find my CustomException in WsSecurityValidationException. The root cause of is 'com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Invalid Username Password Pair'.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Your custom exception extends WsSecurityValidationException exception right?

Comment: No it doesn't. Should it?